# Extract all email in line using awk

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to extract all emails of the line with awk. This is what I tried:

```
echo " test@test.com secondtest@test.com" | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}{while(match($0,/[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/, result) !=0 ) { printf "%s\\n",result[0]; $0 = sub(/[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/,"", $0)}}'
```

But is doesn't work properly. I am expecting the following output:

```
test@test.com 
secondtest@test.com
```

Comment: Note that `\s, \d, \w, \W, \S` etc are PCRE properties, not supported in `awk` regex flavor which is ERE.

Comment: That's not a great regexp for matching email addresses but all that's present in your sample input is valid email addresses separated by spaces so you haven't provided anything for us to test against - we could use a regexp of `[^ ]+` and it'd appear to work given that sample input while if we provided some invalid email addresses then your current regexp would accept them as valid while it wouldn't accept other valid email addresses that are valie, e.g. those with a TLD longer than 4 chars like `.museum`. If you want help with that, search the archives and then ask a new question if necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` you can use a custom `RS` set as one or more whitespaces and use this simpler `awk` that splits each whitespace delimited string as a separate record:

```
echo " test@test.com secondtest@test.com" |
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '/^[^@[:blank:]]+@[^[:blank:]]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2,4}$/'
```

```
test@test.com
secondtest@test.com
```

Comment: Also note that `\s, \d, \w, \W, \S` etc are PCRE properties, not supported in `awk`'s `ERE`.

Answer (score 4):

Using OP's regex here and trying to fix OP's attempt here. We need to use `[[:space:]]` in place of `\s` in code also no need to use `sub` here and simply we could go through all fields one by one with for loop and print the matched one(by using `if` condition in which regex is used, simply if condition satisfies and regex match is TRUE then print that field else do nothing). Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
echo " test@test.com secondtest@test.com" | 
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     if($i~/[^[:space:]]+@[^[:space:]]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2,4}/){  print $i  }
  }
}'
```